# How to search in e-mail BODY in Lotus Notes 8.5.2?

Tags: lotus-notes

I can use the

```
View -->> Search this view
```

to search in the subject of the e-mails. But how can I search ex.: for a string in the Body of the e-mails?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

View->search this view Should search with in the body of the emails in the view as well. If you aren't getting good results you may have to turn on Indexing of your database. If you expand down the search this view bar, there should be an option to update the index. If not there you can do it from one of the tabs on the floating box you get from doing file..database..properties

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following syntax:

```
    [Field] OPERATOR Things to find
```

For example, to find emails from Bert:

```
    [From] CONTAINS Bert
```

Or emails about your 'special project':

```
    [Subject] CONTAINS "Secret Volcano Lair"
```

You can find other operators in the Notes Documentation [here](http://notes.helsinki.fi/help/help8_client.nsf/f4b82fbb75e942a6852566ac0037f284/0e044d2c0639c979852572fe00687f29?OpenDocument).